# Unable to run c/c++ exe from eclipse RCP

Tags: cygwin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to run my `c/c++ .exe` from eclipse `RCP` (Java API).

Code:

```
package com.jkt.rcp.texteditor.handlers;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;

//import com.jkt.runner.utils.Test;

public class RecordHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    private RecordingThread recordingThread;
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("inside RecordHandler...");

        recordingThread = new RecordingThread();

        recordingThread.start();

        return null;
    }



}
```

And code of `RecordingThread.java` is:

```
package com.jkt.rcp.texteditor.handlers;

import java.io.IOException;


public class RecordingThread extends Thread {
    private String file = "C:\\workspace\\JProAcceptanceBot\\Record.exe";

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside Run()...");

        try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(file);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException:"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Actually `RecordHandler.java` executes after clicking a eclipse `RCP` button.
But as soon as I click button, `c/c++ exe` doesn't respond and my Java program stops responding.
Otherwise if I run this `exe` inside my eclipse, it runs fine.

This `c/c++ exe` has been made by using Eclipse CDT and Cygwin.

Please have a look into code and suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you might want to immediately start reading the inputstream of `proc` obtained through proc.GetInputStream(). [In the documentation for `Process`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html):

> All its standard io (i.e. stdin,
>   stdout, stderr) operations will be
>   redirected to the parent process
>   through three streams
>   (Process.getOutputStream(),
>   Process.getInputStream(),
>   Process.getErrorStream()). The parent
>   process uses these streams to feed
>   input to and get output from the
>   subprocess. **Because some native
>   platforms only provide limited buffer
>   size for standard input and output
>   streams, failure to promptly write the
>   input stream or read the output stream
>   of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, and even
>   deadlock.**

[This article on javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) describes the same problem and explains the solution (on page 3).

Comment: I had tried the stuff but no luck.Actually i my native code generates a text file and writes some material to that text file.

Comment: This issue exists regardless of what the .exe does. Have you looked at the output from proc.GetInputStream() in a debugger?

Comment: Thanx jilles.The problem has been solved with your suggestion.Actually i was doing some mishandling with proc.GetInputStream().Now my c/c++ exe runs fine from RCP.

Comment: Good to hear it helped! Reason enough accept my answer perhaps? (click the check-mark to the left of my answer, just below the score)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of [Sun bug 6468220](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6468220) (also described in [bug 6550942](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6550942) and [bug 6511002](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6511002)):

On Windows platform Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray) does not pass correctly command line arguments, if one of them contains double quotes (").

```
Passing/Expected           --> Actual

{ "ab\"c", "d\"ef" }       --> { "abc def" }
{ "a b \" c", "d \" e f" } --> { "a b ", "c d", "e f " }
{ "a", "", "b" }           --> { "a", "b" }
{ "\" a" }                 -->     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

So my question is: what is the exact command line you are trying to execute?